# Powershell import-csv - automatically recognize delimiter?

Tags: powershell, csv

so I work with some CSV files generated on different places. For example server has different regional settings then my laptop so the file can be delimited by , or ;
If I don't specify -delimiter parameter it seems that powershell is simply unable to see that the CSV file is delimited via , so yes use that! I want to have a universal script which does not care about the CSV file origin. Seems like the only way to properly import a CSV file when you don't know the delimiter is something like this:

```
$line=gc "list1.csv"|select -first 1
if($line-like "*,*" -and -not ($line-like "*;*")){
    $list1=Import-Csv "list1.csv" -Delimiter ","
}else{
    $list1=Import-Csv "list1.csv" -Delimiter ";"
}
```

Anybody has a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so better idea, just refactoring :

```bsh
$line = Get-Content "list1.csv" | Select -First 1
$delimiter = if($line.Split(";").Length -gt 1){";"}else{","};
$list1 = Import-Csv "list1.csv" -Delimiter $delimiter
```

Of course this works only if your delimiter is `,` or `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily make it much readable using a `switch` in PowerShell

There's nothing on PowerShell that would automatically determine the delimiter. You could create a function that can do this with the following switch statements:

```
$a = $line -like "*,*"
$b = $line -like "*;*"

switch($True) {
  $a    {Import-Csv "list.csv" -Delimiter ","}
  $b    {Import-Csv "list.csv" -Delimiter ";"}
  Default {Write-Error "Cannot determine delimiter"}
}
```

Although, if there are different delimiters you want to add in, you would have to work out the logic. That, I leave up to you to do :).